# How to write a Arabic text file with indentation?

Tags: c#, file, office-interop, arabic, arabic-support

In my current work I need to read content from a `.docx` file and write its content to a plain Text file, which will be input for other task.

Below is my sample code which work for me for most of language but for arabic I got an issue as arabic is right to left.

```
StringBuilder docText = new StringBuilder();
Document currentDoc = word.Documents.Open(file.FullName);
foreach (Paragraph p in currentDoc.Paragraphs)
{
    string paraText = p.Range.Text;
    docText.AppendLine(paraText);
}
currentDoc.Close(false);
if (docText.Length > 0)
{
    string outputTxtpath = output + @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name) + ".txt";
    File.WriteAllText(outputTxtpath, docText.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

For arabic I am facing 2 issues:

1. Text in txt file is in left indentation.
2. If a paragraph is starting with a number (Image 1), then that number come left side in the text file (Image 2), whereas other arabic character sequence is as it is, which is a issue for my 2nd tool.

Sample input (`.docx` file) and output (`.txt` file) uploaded to below location. searched a lot for the issue but everywhere I am getting a solution for how to read a Arabic text file.

Docx File : https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ah-Jh2Ok5SuHgQEl90D9NXlM0CJw
Text File : https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ah-Jh2Ok5SuHgQAEPZur1A3379mr

[image: OriginalText from DOCX file]
[image: Converted Text from TXT file]

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing a slightly different method to save the `Word.Document` file, using the internal [Document.SaveAs2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.SaveAs2);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method, using [Encoded Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) as output format.

This allows you to use the [Microsoft Office Unicode encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true), which should cover all possible language Encodings.

It also lets you specify how the Bi-Directional Marks should be treated. If this otion is set to `true`, the Bidirectional original setting is preserved.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document DefaultDocument;

DefaultDocument = WordApplication.Documents.Open(FilePath);
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo((int)DefaultDocument.Content.LanguageID);

string SaveFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath), 
                                   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath));
DefaultDocument.SaveAs2(SaveFileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatEncodedText, Type.Missing, 
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                        MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUnicodeLittleEndian, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                        Type.Missing, true); //<- BiDi Marks

//Release the Document
foreach (Document WDocument in WordApplication.Documents)
{
    WDocument.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(WDocument);
}

//Release the WINWORD Process
WordApplication.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(WordApplication);
Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext();

//Test the results using a RichTextBox
richTextBox1.RightToLeft = (culture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft) ? RightToLeft.Yes : RightToLeft.No;
richTextBox1.ImeMode = ImeMode.On;
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(SaveFileName + ".txt");
```

This is the result as shown in the RichTextBox control.

[image]

As an alternative to `Document.SaveAs2`, you could derive the Encoding from the [Document.LanguageID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdlanguageid-enumeration-word) numeric value, which references the `CultureInfo` culture identifier (LCID).
(`culture` has already been defined in the previous code)

```
Encoding encoding = (culture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)
                    ? Encoding.GetEncoding(culture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage)
                    : Encoding.Unicode;

using (MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(DefaultDocument.Content.Text)))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(MemStream, encoding))
    File.WriteAllText(SaveFileName + ".txt", reader.ReadToEnd());
```